# Using jqGrid I need to Show a Hidden Column Based on UserData Parm

Tags: free-jqgrid

Using jqGrid 4.15.6-pre - free jqGrid

I am wondering why the following code will not show the specified column.

```
var cm = $('#nrtslist').jqGrid('getColProp','override');
            cm.hidden = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done this way.
All the concept of the grid is that you can read the properties of colModel or any other grid option, but changing it does not mean that it will change something. With other words something must happen in order to change the property.
These properties describe the current status (in most cases) or this is a consequence, not a cause.

To change something in grid you will need to use the appropriate method or do your own one.

In your case you will need to use the **showCol** or **hideCol** methods

```
$('#nrtslist').jqGrid('showCol','override'); // this will show the column
$('#nrtslist').jqGrid('hideCol','override'); // this will hide it.
```